# Como emular el ciclo do-while en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

alguno de ustedes me podría indicar como emular el ciclo do-while en python, buscando por en diferentes paginas encontré el siguiente código

```
 while True:
     stuff() #que hace esa funcion o alguno puede ser tan amable de darme un ejemplo de uso
     if fail_condition:
     break
```

eso era todo muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Cesar, primer que nada el break está mal identado, ya que corresponde al `if`. Por otro lado `stuff()` imagino que simplemente es para ejemplificar que en esa parte se hace algo. Saludos

Comment: a ok muchas gracias, eso me tenia con la cabeza a punto de explotar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es tal y como dices, pero para ponerte un ejemplo con el que respaldarte podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
i = 1

while True:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    if(i > 3):
        break
```

Entiendo que se ve rápido, pero lo que haces es un do-while el cual, en C por ejemplo, sería así:

```
int i = 1;

do{
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = i + 1;
} while(i <= 3);
```

Comment: gracias por la explicación ya entendí la cosa.

Comment: De nada, un placer :)

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres evitar el `break` (algunos puristas consideran que el `break` no es programación estructurada y no debe usarse), tienes la siguiente opción, que para mi gusto es peor, pero bueno:

```py
i = 1
repetir_bucle = True
while repetir_bucle:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    if i>3:
       repetir_bucle = False
```

O para que la condición de salida sea aún más parecida a la de un bucle `do...while` del C:

```py
i = 1
repetir_bucle = True
while repetir_bucle:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    repetir_bucle = (i<=3)
```

que para mi gusto es aún más fea que la anterior. Yo me quedaría con la solución `break`, pero para gustos...

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy informativa e ilustrativa.

Comment: En python no es exáctamente equivalente. Los bucles, como `while`, pueden tener un bloque `else` que se ejecuta únicamente cuando se cumple la condición de salida, pero no con el `break`. IMHO, no creo que sea bueno forzar el cumplimiento de la condición de salida, lo  importante es que se entienda lo que hace el bucle.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor forma sería esta.
Creas una variable para activar solo una vez, la siguiente se ejecutará dependiendo del valor de la variable testeada. Por ejemplo este código se ejecutará solo una vez. Si el X está en el rango hará las iteraciones necesarias, pero si no lo está, se ejecutará sólo una vez.

```
x = 25
r = True
while x < 10 or r:
   r = False
   x += 1
```